# WebSettingsCompat (setForceDark) not working on android 13

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm using `WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(webView.getSettings(), WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_OFF);` on android 12 is working well, but on android 13 it not working. please help and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For apps targeting Android 13 (API level 33) or higher, the `setForceDark()` method is deprecated, resulting in a no-op if the method is called.

Instead, WebView now always sets the media query `prefers-color-scheme` according to the app's theme attribute, [isLightTheme](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#Theme_isLightTheme). In other words, if `isLightTheme` is true or not specified, `prefers-color-scheme` is light; otherwise, it is dark. This behavior means that the web content's light or dark style is applied automatically to match the app's theme if the content supports it.

For most apps, the new behavior should apply the appropriate app styles automatically, however you should test your app to check for any cases where you might've been manually controlling dark mode settings.

If you still need to customize your app's color theme behavior, use the [setAlgorithmicDarkeningAllowed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setAlgorithmicDarkeningAllowed(boolean)) method instead. For backward compatibility with previous Android versions, we recommend using the equivalent [setAlgorithmicDarkeningAllowed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setAlgorithmicDarkeningAllowed(boolean)) method in AndroidX.

See the documentation for that method to learn more about what behavior you can expect in your app depending on your app's targetSdkVersion and theme settings.

For more info, visit to this docs https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        if (SDK_INT >= 32) { 
            if (WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.ALGORITHMIC_DARKENING)) {
                try {       WebSettingsCompat.setAlgorithmicDarkeningAllowed(myWebView.getSettings(), true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }else {

            if (WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.FORCE_DARK)) {

                int nightModeFlags = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;

                if (nightModeFlags == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
                    //Theme is switched to Night/Dark mode, turn on webview darkening
                    WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(myWebView.getSettings(), WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_ON);
                }
```

Comment: can you please  explain what the code is doing ?